# selection menu for iframe src using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, selection, src

I found out how to use javascript to change the iframe src, but when I made a selection menu that allows you to choose the url to load in, it only loads the first option in the menu, even when you select a different url. I got it to work once, but I made a few changes and it wouldn't let me go all the way back with undo. Here's what I've got:

```html
<iframe src="http://jquery.com/" id="myFrame" width="500" height="500" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>
<div>
  <select id="selected2">
    <option value="http://linux.com">1</option>
    <option value="http://microsoft.com">2</option>
    <option value="http://apple.com">3</option>
  </select>
  <button onclick="loadPages()">Click Me</button>
  <script>
    function loadPages() {
      var loc = dataCap;
      document.getElementById('myFrame').setAttribute('src', loc);
    }
    var dataCap = document.getElementById("selected2").value;
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is that you're only getting the value the first time around, when your script executes. In order to get the currently selected value, you need to get the value right when you click the button, inside of the `onclick` function.

http://jsfiddle.net/v74ypgwk/1/

```
<iframe src="http://jquery.com/" id="myFrame" width="500" height="500" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>
<div>
<select id="selected2">
    <option value="http://linux.com">1</option>
    <option value="http://microsoft.com">2</option>
    <option value="http://apple.com">3</option>
</select>
<button onclick="loadPages()">Click Me</button>
<script>
var urlSelect = document.getElementById('selected2'),
    myFrame = document.getElementById('myFrame');
function loadPages() {
    var loc = urlSelect.value;
    // You can also do -> myFrame.src = loc;
    myFrame.setAttribute('src', loc);
}
</script>
```