# I would like to change iframe sorce with HTML Get

Tags: javascript, html, url, curl, get

I would like to change the iframe src URL using a URL. For example, if I input this URL `http://simplesite.com/videoiframe.html?txtUrl=https://www.simplesite.com&press=Go` to the browser and submit, it should change the iframe's src part to `https://www.simplesite.com` and press the button "Go".

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setBrowserFrameSource(){
        var browserFrame = document.getElementById("browser");
        browserFrame.src= document.getElementById("txtUrl").value;
    }
</script>
</head>
<div visibility="hidden">

<form method="post" target="browser">
<input id="txtUrl" style="width:82%;" placeholder="Put the website here" name="url" type="text" />
<input style="width:8%;" type="button" value="Go" onclick="setBrowserFrameSource(); return false;"/>
</form>
</div>
<iframe id="browser" name="browser" src="http://google.com" style="height:100%; width:100%"></iframe>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [selection menu for iframe src using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30408007/selection-menu-for-iframe-src-using-javascript)

Comment: Note: the `<input>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can recover address bare url with `window.location.href` then parse it through URL object and extract GET searchParams.

To reuse code you should allow your function to admit arguments.

Then wait till DOM is loaded to allow it to read and write DOM element tags.

This snippet should do the trick.

```
function setBrowserFrameSource( getParameter = null ) {
  var browserFrame = document.getElementById("browser");
  var urlName = document.getElementById("urlName");
  if ( getParameter === null ) {
    browserFrame.src = document.getElementById("txtUrl").value;
  } else {
    browserFrame.src = getParameter;
  }
}

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var url = new URL(window.location.href);
  var getParam = url.searchParams.get("txtUrl");
  if ( getParam !== null ) {
    setBrowserFrameSource( getParam );
  }
})
```